# Proving the relation: $∇(\mathbf{u}·\mathbf{v})=(\mathbf{v}·∇)\mathbf{u}+(\mathbf{u}·∇)\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}×(∇×\mathbf{u})+\mathbf{u}×(∇×\mathbf{v})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have to prove the following relation. I am looking for a solution beyond the obvious brute force method of considering $\mathbf{u}=u_1\mathbf{i}+u_2\mathbf{j}+u_3\mathbf{k}\;and\;\mathbf{v}=v_1\mathbf{i}+v_2\mathbf{j}+v_3\mathbf{k}$ putting in these values and simply showing that the two sides come to the same result through a long and tedious calculation. Any thoughts?

$$∇(\mathbf{u}·\mathbf{v})=(\mathbf{v}·∇)\mathbf{u}+(\mathbf{u}·∇)\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}×(∇×\mathbf{u})+\mathbf{u}×(∇×\mathbf{v})\;where\;\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\;are\;vectors$$

**P.S:** I was not very sure whether I have added the correct tags or not. Feel free to add or remove tags as you deem appropriate.

Comment: Yo, Mr. White! Have you thought about using index notation? It's a much-better way to vectorial identities.

Comment: Search$\,$ _gradient of a dot product_ $\dots$

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$ functions of?  At this point the question does not seem to make much sense.  If they are really just vectors, then the dot product is a constant function, and the gradient is $0$.  Maybe you mean $u$ and $v$ are vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1):

A rather vanilla, if tedious, application associativity of the clifford algebra's geometric product and  grade projection gets the job done.

$$\langle \nabla (uv)\rangle_1 = (\nabla \cdot u) v + (\nabla \wedge u) \cdot v + (u \cdot \nabla) v - (u \wedge \nabla) \cdot v = \nabla (u \cdot v) + \nabla \cdot (u \wedge v)$$

Apply the BAC-CAB rule to the last term:

$$\nabla \cdot (u \wedge v) = (\nabla \cdot u) v + (u \cdot \nabla) v - (\nabla \cdot v) u - (v \cdot \nabla) u$$

You'll note that the $(\nabla \cdot u) v + (u \cdot \nabla) v$ terms cancel, but some other terms do not:

$$\nabla (u \cdot v) = (\nabla \wedge u) \cdot v - (u \wedge \nabla) \cdot v + (\nabla \cdot v)u + (v \cdot \nabla) u$$

Not much to do but directly attack that $(u \wedge \nabla) \cdot v$ term:

$$(u \wedge \nabla) \cdot v = (\nabla \cdot v) u - \dot \nabla (\dot v \cdot u)$$

The dots mean that $\dot \nabla$ differentiates only $\dot v$ in $\dot v \cdot u$; effectively, $u$ is "held constant."

Great, so what is $\dot \nabla (\dot v \cdot u)$?  Let's grade project again.

$$\langle (\nabla v) u \rangle_1 = (\nabla \cdot v) u + (\nabla \wedge v) \cdot u = \dot \nabla (\dot v \cdot u) + \dot \nabla \cdot (\dot v \wedge u) =\dot \nabla (\dot v \cdot u) + (\nabla \cdot v) u - (u \cdot \nabla) v$$

Putting that all together gives us

$$(u \wedge \nabla) \cdot v = (\nabla \cdot v) u - (u \cdot \nabla) v - (\nabla \wedge v) \cdot u$$

So the final result is

$$\nabla (u \cdot v) = (\nabla \wedge u) \cdot v + (u \cdot \nabla) v + (\nabla \wedge v) \cdot u + (v \cdot \nabla) u $$

Finally, note that the wedge and generalized dot products here are related to cross products or curl like so:

$$(\nabla \wedge u) \cdot v = [i(\nabla \times u)] \cdot v = i[ (\nabla \times u) \wedge v ] = -(\nabla \times u) \times v$$

That allows us to recover the more familiar result.